# Remove and modify a selected item from listbox that uses datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, datasource

I have a GUI that I am creating which reads a .csv file into a listbox and I am trying to remove a country that is selected when the application is running using a button. I have tried multiple codes however nothing works I either get a error message "**Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.**" or nothing happens. below is what I have at the moment. I am also trying to modify a selected item using textboxes.

```
namespace Countries
{

  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
      public Form1()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }

      private IList<tradingDetails> listOfCountries;

      public class tradingDetails
      {
          public string Country { get; set; }
          public string GDP { get; set; }
          public string Inflation { get; set; }
          public string TB { get; set; }
          public string HDI { get; set; }
          public string TP { get; set; }

          public string Display
          {
              get
              {
                  return string.Format("Country = {0} --- GDP = {1} --- Inflation = {2} --- TB = {3} --- HDI = {4} --- TP = {5}", this.Country, this.GDP, this.Inflation, this.TB, this.HDI, this.TP);

              }
          }
      }

      public static string[] headers { get; set; }

      public void load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          this.listOfCountries = new List<tradingDetails>();
          this.listBox1.ValueMember = "Countries";
          this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "Display";
          this.InsertInfo();
          this.listBox1.DataSource = this.listOfCountries;
      }

      public void InsertInfo()
      {
          OpenFileDialog browse = new OpenFileDialog();
          browse.Multiselect = true;
          if (browse.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
          {
              string selectedFile = browse.FileName;
              const int MAX_SIZE = 5000;
              string[] AllLines = new string[MAX_SIZE];

              AllLines = File.ReadAllLines(selectedFile);
              foreach (string line in AllLines)
              {
                  if (line.StartsWith("Country"))
                  {
                    headers = line.Split(',');
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      string[] columns = line.Split(',');

                      tradingDetails fileCountry = new tradingDetails
                      {
                          Country = columns[0],
                          GDP = columns[1],
                          Inflation = columns[2],
                          TB = columns[3],
                          HDI = columns[4],
                          TP = columns[5]
                      };

                      this.listOfCountries.Add(fileCountry);

                  }
              }
          }
      }

      private void DataBind()
      {
          listBox1.BeginUpdate();
          listBox1.DataSource = listOfCountries;
          listBox1.EndUpdate();
      }
      private void remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         for (int x = listBox1.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; x >= 0; x--)
          {
              int idx = listBox1.SelectedIndices[x];
              listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(idx);
          }
      }

      private void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          listBox1.SelectedItems.Clear();

          for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
          {
              if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text))
              {
                  listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);
              }
          }
      }

      private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          textBox2.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
      }
  }
```

}

**UPDATE**
I have tried this however this deletes all the information in the combo box and not an individual item.

```
    private void remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DataSource = null;
        comboBox1.Items.Remove(comboBox1.SelectedValue);
        comboBox1.DataSource = listOfCountries;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove items from listbox while it's bounded with a source. For a better understanding, you are trying to remove the item, that your listbox is not an owner of, but the source is(that you have set the datasource of listbox).
Instead, you need to remove the item from the datasource itself.

```
private void remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int x = listBox1.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; x >= 0; x--)
    {
        int idx = listBox1.SelectedIndices[x];
        //listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(idx);
        listOfCountries.RemoveAt(idx)l
    }
    listBox1.RefreshItems();
}
```

Also, as you are trying to clear all the items from your listbox, this not a good approach to iterate every items and remove all. Instead, you should either clear your `listOfCountries` or set the `listbox1`datasource as null.

Comment: Iv tried that before it doesnt work, I dont want to actually remove the data itself just remove it from the list. also the RefreshItem doesnt work. I also was thinking about changing the box to a combobox but im not sure if that will require rewriting entire code.

Comment: In that case, bind the listbox with a temporary source having that particular items remove.

Comment: i dont know how to do that.. sorry about this im kinda new to all this